# Anonymous function in php

Tags: php, anonymous-types

Imagine (even if it's not good style) you have an array in which you are adding **Arrays** with some content.
Maybe something like this:

```
$result_array = array();

foreach( ... as $key => $value ) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp["start"] = $value->start;
    $temp["end"] = $value->end;
    $result_array[] = $temp;
}

// Image it will produce for example an $result_array like this:
   array(
       array("start" => 10, "end" => 20), 
       array("start" => 100, "end" => 120)
   );
```

So far so good. Now lets do some dirty things like this: 
I want to add a anonymous function that returns the span between **start** and **end** in each temp_array. This could look something like this:

```
foreach( ... as $key => $value ) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp["start"] = $value->start;
    $temp["end"] = $value->end;
    $temp["duration"] = function() { return abs( __START__ - __END__ ); }
    $result_array[] = $temp;
}
```

As I am in an "Array" and I don't know my index, how can I access my start and end time?

Please don't flame me for bad style or syntax errors, it's just an example that I wrote down in the question field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymous function does not have any connection with its "context array". You cannot get the values of the array the function is in because there's no inherent connection between the function and the array. The best you could do is give it the values via a closure upon creation:

```
$temp['duration'] = function () use ($value) { return abs($value->start - $value->end); }
```

This doesn't work in a loop of course, since the value of `$value` changes, so you need a function producing function to break that reference:

```
$temp['duration'] = call_user_func(function ($v) {
    return function () use ($v) { return abs($v->start - $v->end); };
}, $value);
```

I'm not sure why you'd go through all this trouble though instead of just calculating and inserting the value into the array as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if for some reason (unknown to me) this is a bad practice, but you can use references like this:

```
$temp["start"] = $value->start;
$start = &$temp["start"];
$temp["end"] = $value->end;
$end = &$temp["end"];
$temp["duration"] = function() use (&$start, &$end) { return abs( $start - $end ); };
```

By the way, is there a reason you want to make a "lazy" operation on those values?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant why can't you just calculate the value while you're looping instead of use an anonymous function. Do those values changes after that loop?